# Twitter API Javascript extended mode

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, twitter

I am using twitter stream API with Javascript in order to collect tweets. The problem is that I am not using the extended mode and I don't get the full tweet when it is greater than 140 characters. I have searched info and I discovered that I need to pass tweet_mode=extended in the request and the response will contain a full_text which is the tweet complete. The problem is that I don't know where to write tweet_mode=extended. This is my code:

```
    twitter.stream('statuses/filter', {track: word, function (stream) {
            stream.on('data', function (tweet) {
                 console.log(tweet.text)
            });
            stream.on('error', function (error) {
                console.log("error:", error);
            })
        })
```

Comment: Which library are you using? Their documentation probably provides a place for sending arbitrary parameters in the request.

Comment: The twitter standard library [https://developer.twitter.com/en.html]

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately the streaming API does not have the option to add the tweet_mode param

Documentation here: https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/tweets/tweet-updates

This paragraph is of note to your concern:

> The Streaming API does not provide the same ability to provide query
>   parameters to configure request options. Therefore, the Streaming API
>   renders all Tweets in compatibility mode at this time.
>
> ...
>
> Streaming API consumers should update their code to first check for
>   the presence of the extended_tweet dictionary, and use that in
>   preference to the truncated data as is applicable for their use case.
>   When extended_tweet is not present, they must fall back to using the
>   existing fields.

Comment: I don't think so that you are right because a lot of people have done it before and if it wasn't possible why would they put different modes in their documentation?

Comment: If I'm reading the docs correctly, I think those mode options are for a REST API and not their streaming API

Comment: You can check the returned JSON for the `truncated` field, which should at least tell you whether or not the tweet is a big one

Answer (score 1):

As Van said, tweets in streaming API are mixed. So you can try this :

```
twitter.stream('statuses/filter', {track: word, function (stream) {
        stream.on('data', function (tweet) {
             let text = tweet.extended_tweet?tweet.extended_tweet.full_text:tweet.full_text?tweet.full_text:tweet.text;
             console.log(text)
        });
        stream.on('error', function (error) {
            console.log("error:", error);
        })
    })
```